# I'm not sure how to correctly configure my server setup

Tags: node.js, server

This is kind of a multi-tiered question in which my end goal is to establish the best way to setup my server which will be hosting a website as well as a service (using Socket.io) for an iOS (and eventually an Android) app. Both the app service and the website are going to be written in node.js as I need high concurrency and scaling for the app server and I figured whilst I'm at it may as well do the website in node because it wouldn't be that much different in terms of performance than something different like Apache (from my understanding).

Also the website has a lower priority than the app service, the app service should receive significantly higher traffic than the website (but in the long run this may change). Money isn't my greatest priority here, but it is a limiting factor, I feel that having a service that has 99.9% uptime (as 100% uptime appears to be virtually impossible in the long run) is more important than saving money at the compromise of having more down time.

Firstly I understand that having one node process per cpu core is the best way to fully utilise a multi-core cpu. I now understand after researching that running more than one per core is inefficient due to the fact that the cpu has to do context switching between the multiple processes. How come then whenever I see code posted on how to use the in-built cluster module in node.js, the master worker creates a number of workers equal to the number of cores because that would mean you would have 9 processes on an 8 core machine (1 master process and 8 worker processes)? Is this because the master process usually is there just to restart worker processes if they crash or end and therefore does so little it doesnt matter that it shares a cpu core with another node process?

If this is the case then, I am planning to have the workers handle providing the app service and have the master worker handle the workers but also host a webpage which would provide statistical information on the server's state and all other relevant information (like number of clients connected, worker restart count, error logs etc). Is this a bad idea? Would it be better to have this webpage running on a separate worker and just leave the master worker to handle the workers?

So overall I wanted to have the following elements; a service to handle the request from the app (my main point of traffic), a website (fairly simple, a couple of pages and a registration form), an SQL database to store user information, a webpage (probably locally hosted on the server machine) which only I can access that hosts information about the server (users connected, worker restarts, server logs, other useful information etc) and apparently nginx would be a good idea where I'm handling multiple node processes accepting connection from the app. After doing research I've also found that it would probably be best to host on a VPS initially. I was thinking at first when the amount of traffic the app service would be receiving will most likely be fairly low, I could run all of those elements on one VPS. Or would it be best to have them running on seperate VPS's except for the website and the server status webpage which I could run on the same one? I guess this way if there is a hardware failure and something goes down, not everything does and I could run 2 instances of the app service on 2 different VPS's so if one goes down the other one is still functioning. Would this just be overkill? I doubt for a while I would need multiple app service instances to support the traffic load but it would help reduce the apparent down time for users.

Maybe this all depends on what I value more and have the time to do? A more complex server setup that costs more and maybe a little unnecessary but guarantees a consistent and reliable service, or a cheaper and simpler setup that may succumb to downtime due to coding errors and server hardware issues.

Also it's worth noting I've never had any real experience with production level servers so in some ways I've jumped in the deep end a little with this. I feel like I've come a long way in the past half a year and feel like I'm getting a fairly good grasp on what I need to do, I could just do with some advice from someone with experience that has an idea with what roadblocks I may come across along the way and whether I'm causing myself unnecessary problems with this kind of setup.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: I would recommend breaking this into smaller questions.  This is a little difficult to answer due to the shear number of questions and broadness of the post.

Comment: @tier1 I was thinking of doing that but then I felt all questions required the full context of the issue. I could maybe number the relevant paragraphs to kind of split it up more?